How to Add a Confirmation Popup Before Sending Emails in Outlook Using VB.NET
I am working on creating a custom feature for Microsoft Outlook using VB.NET. My goal is to intercept the email-sending process and display a confirmation popup asking, "Do you want to send this email?" before the email is sent. If the user clicks "No," the email should not be sent.
I have attempted to use the Application.ItemSend event to implement this feature. Below is the code I have written:
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim response As Integer
    ' Confirm before sending the email
    response = MsgBox("Do you want to send this email?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Send Confirmation")
    
    If response = vbNo Then
        ' If user clicks No, cancel sending the email
        Cancel = True
    Else
        ' If user clicks Yes, proceed with sending the email
        Cancel = False
    End If
End Sub


My goal is to intercept the email-sending process and display a confirmation popup asking, "Do you want to send this email?" before the email is sent: For what purpose? If a user didn't want to send an e-mail he/she/they wouldn't have clicked the Send button. If you think that this is something necessary/worthwhile, you may consider submitting a feature request to MS.
